# How does this python factory function work

Tags: python, python-3.x, closures

This is the python function from my pluralsight python class:

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp
```

And the instructor now opens an interactive session and does the following:

- from raise_to import raise_to
- square = raise_to(2), and then goes on to do
- square(5)

and that produces the result of 25. How or why pass in two distinct arguments? Now I ran a debug on this code and this is what I observed. When I do this:

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp

square = raise_to(2)

print(square)
```

I get : `<function raise_to.<locals>.raise_to_exp at 0x00000246D1A88700>`, but if I do as the instructor

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp

square = raise_to(2)

print(square(5))
```

I get 25. I would like to know how this works. I know this is referred as a python factory function but how does it work. Is the function storing the first argument for later use with the second argument passed in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`raise_to_exp` is a *closure* over the parameter `exp` defined by `raise_to`. When you call `raise_to(2)`, you get back a function in whose body the variable `exp` refers to the variable in the scope where `raise_to_exp` was defined.

This means that `square` is a function where `exp` is bound to 2, so roughly equivalent to the definition

```
def square(x):
    return pow(x, 2)
```

---

Just to prove that there was no *replacement* of `exp` with the value 2, you can do a bit of digging into the `function` object to *change* the value of `exp`.

```
>>> square(5)
25
>>> square.__closure__[0].cell_contents = 3  # now square is cube!
>>> square(5)
125
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def raise_to(exp):
    def raise_to_exp(x):
        return pow(x, exp)
    return raise_to_exp
```

I made the last statement bold. You're returning a function here. Think of it as

```
a=lambda x:x+1
a(1)
# 2
```

When you do

```
square=raise_to(2)
```

Now `square` refers to the function `raise_to_exp` because `raise_to` returned the `raise_to_exp` function. `square` can be used as a function here.

```
square(2) # with exp set as 2
# 4

cube=raise_to(3)
cube(2)
# 8
```